# SVN error when trying to merge from a branch

Tags: svn, merge, branch, visualsvn, trunk

I'm trying to merge changes from a branch to the trunk, for a single file and a single revision.

I'm using VisualSVN as the front-end.

So I right-click the file, Visual SVN -> Merge, then select ‘Merge a range of revisions’, then enter the revision number (from the log) and hit Next. Then I click ‘Test Merge’

What I get is the following error:

> 'http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/md5-checksum' was not present on the resource.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yay! A colleague figured out the problem.

Even though I was right-clicking on the *file* and clicking 'Merge', the 'merge from' URL was set to the top-level folder of the branch.

> http://server.svn/Project/branches/1.0.2

It should have specified the full path and filename of the file

> http://server.svn/Project/branches/1.0.2**/folder/blah.cs**

Now I'm all the wiser. :)

Comment: According to the "merging best practices" in the svn book, merges should only be performed on the root of the branch: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.finalword

Comment: That would explain why Tortoise defaults to the root path. However in this particular situation, I had to apply the merge to specific files.

Comment: Not all situations match "best practice" (although its a good point). Thanks for the answer - saved my day.

Comment: Awesome! i should've searched SO two hours ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, however, it turned out that an empty file (literally 0 (zero) bytes) was located in the repository. Apparently something SVN doesn't know how to handle. After removing this file, everything did work again.